# Время запуска анимации на CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Есть два элемента с одинаковой анимацией, нужно сделать так, чтобы анимация у них происходила не синхронно?

Возможно ли это сделать на СSS?

```css
.block_1 {
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.block_2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 400px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0; //0
    margin: -25px 0 0 -28px;
    animation: pulsate 2s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -26px 0 0 -28px;
    animation: pulsate 4s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.2);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.2);
    opacity: .3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="block_2">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[Пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/WjyEvz)

Answer (score 0):

Да, примените к одному из кругов:

```
.block_2 .circle {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
}
```

[Смотреть на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/zt889eLh/)

Comment: А если таких кругов будет много?

Comment: Можно извернуться с циклами в sass, но я бы уделил время на изучение GSAP (https://greensock.com) для такого.